# How to make a back button in a same html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have pages in one html page like the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    <p>Hi hello how are you This is page 1 </p>
  </br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">
  <button>Next Page</button>

  </a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
   <p> I'm fine thanks Thıs is page 2 </p>
</br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page3','Page2');">

  <button>Next Page</button>
</a>
  </div>

<div id="Page3" style="display:none">
   <p>What is your name Thıs is page 3 </p>
</br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to make a back button but there is a little problem. I change the current page to the another page with my web services result for example if my webservice returns "3" my current page will hide and the third page will open.How can I make a back button? I tried to make like ; But it's not working because all of them on the same html file

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That wont work since you're not really changing pages. You will need to keep a reference to the previous/current page before the switch in a variable then on switch do the reverse of what you do to change page.

Something like:

```
var previous;
var current;
function show(shown, hidden) {
  previous = hidden;
  current= shown
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}

function goBack() {
  show(previous, current)
}
```

Note that this wont address the browser back button. It is possible to make that work but it get more complex as you need to tap into the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or some similar setup that can manage url history for you (and fake it as in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is what you're expected behaviour is.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var oldPages = [],
      shownPage;

    function toggleShow(shown, hidden) {
      if (shown && hidden) {
        oldPages.push(hidden);
        shownPage = shown;
      } else {
        hidden = shownPage;
        shownPage = shown = oldPages[oldPages.length - 1];
        oldPages.pop();
      }
      if (!shown) {
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById(hidden).style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    <p>Hi hello how are you This is page 1</p>
    </br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return toggleShow('Page2','Page1');">
      <button>Next Page</button>

    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    <p>I'm fine thanks Thıs is page 2</p>
    </br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return toggleShow('Page3','Page2');">

      <button>Next Page</button>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page3" style="display:none">
    <p>What is your name Thıs is page 3</p>
    </br>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
  <button onclick="toggleShow()">back!</button>
</body>

</html>
```